# ubuntu 18.04 not mounting usb flashdrive without rebooting with flashdrive installed in USB port

Tags: usb, mount

I recently updated to 18.04 from 16.04. now my flashdrives and printer not found when I plug them in after ubuntu running. I have to leave them plugged in and reboot to see and use drives and printer. 16.04 used to give me access to anything I plugged in while running.

Comment: I also have this problem with my front USB port. I also need to keep my USB flash drives plugged in and then boot up to use them. Previously I did not have this problem, but I forget whether the fresh install of 18.04 is the cause. (I'm using HP Z840. The back ports work well. My USB keyboard and mouse works well on both front and back ports)

Answer (score 1):

I used the steps given in [this article](https://techiesanswer.com/ubuntu-command-line/how-to-mount-usb-flash-drive/).

Open a terminal and connect the USB. Then type at the command line:

```
lsusb
```

Find that your USB is detected. Once it is known, then enter at the command line:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This will give the location of the mount for the USB. Now enter:

```
 sudo mount /dev/<location like sbd> /mnt/
```

This will mount all types of USBs. Files will be visible in the file manager under the name of the USB.

This will be alive till you switch of the computer. You can change USB.
Please remove them with eject button.

In the end enter at command prompt:

```
umount /mnt
```

This works for me.